# Asp.net mvc6 app receives null parameter from web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

My controller should receive a certain object from the caller when an api is used but in my case it receives the object of the type that i requested but with the proprieties set to null.The parameter has [FromBody] etiquette but I also tried [FromForm] and eliminating the etiquette completely but the result is almost the same with the difference that when i use [FromBody] my app throws an Null exception when i try to access a certain field from the object and in the other cases the proprieties are just set to default values(if it's a int is 0 and for a string is ""). If it helps..I am calling the api from a swagger generated page.

Here is my object:

```
using AT.Core.Cqrs;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DotnetProject.BusinessLayer.Implementation.Queries
{
    public class GetTestByIdQuery : IQuery
    {
        public int TestId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The http end point from the controller:

```
 [HttpGet]
    [Route("getTest")]
    public int GetTest([FromServices]GetTestByIdQueryHandler handler,[FromBody]GetTestByIdQuery query)
    {
        return query.TestId;   
    }
```

And my ConfigureServices function from startup:

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials());
        });




        // Add framework services.
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);
        services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
        services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<ITestRepository, TestRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<ITestService, TestService>();
        services.AddScoped<IRoleService, RoleService>();
        services.AddScoped<IRoleRepository, RoleRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<ICommandHandler<DeleteUserCommand>, DeleteUserHandler>();
        services.AddScoped<ICommandHandler<UpdateUserCommand>,UpdateUserHandler>();
        services.AddScoped<ICommandHandler<AddUserCommand>, AddUserHandler>();
        services.AddScoped<ICommandHandler<DeleteTestCommand>, DeleteTestHandler>();
        services.AddScoped<ICommandHandler<UpdateTestCommand>, UpdateTestHandler>();
        services.AddScoped<ICommandHandler<AddTestCommand>, AddTestHandler>();
        services.AddScoped<IQueryHandler<GetAllTestsQuery,GetAllTestsQueryResult>,GetAllTestsQueryHandler>();
        services.AddScoped<IQueryHandler<GetTestByIdQuery, GetTestByIdQueryResult>,GetTestByIdQueryHandler>();
        services.AddScoped<IQueryHandler<GetAllUsersQuery, GetAllUsersQueryResult>, GetAllUsersQueryHandler>();
        services.AddScoped<IQueryHandler<GetUserByIdQuery, GetUserByIdQueryResult>, GetUserByIdQueryHandler>();
        services.AddScoped<GetAllTestsQueryHandler, GetAllTestsQueryHandler >();
        services.AddScoped<GetTestByIdQueryHandler, GetTestByIdQueryHandler>();
        services.AddScoped<GetAllUsersQueryHandler, GetAllUsersQueryHandler>();
        services.AddScoped <GetUserByIdQueryHandler, GetUserByIdQueryHandler> ();
        services.AddScoped <AddTestHandler, AddTestHandler> ();
        services.AddScoped <AddUserHandler, AddUserHandler> ();
        services.AddScoped <DeleteTestHandler, DeleteTestHandler> ();
        services.AddScoped <DeleteUserHandler, DeleteUserHandler> ();
        services.AddScoped <UpdateTestHandler, UpdateTestHandler> ();
        services.AddScoped <UpdateUserHandler, UpdateUserHandler> ();

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>();
        services.AddMvc(config =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            config.OutputFormatters.Clear();
            config.OutputFormatters.Add(new JsonOutputFormatter(new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
            }, ArrayPool<char>.Shared));
        });

        services
    .AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(jsonOptions =>
    {
        jsonOptions.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
    });
        // Inject an implementation of ISwaggerProvider with defaulted settings applied
        services.AddSwaggerGen();
    }
```

EDIT: Headers+body when i use [FromBody] etiquette.

```
Curl
curl -X GET --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{ \ 
   "testId": 60 \ 
 }' 'http://localhost:5000/api/Test/getTest'
Request URL
http://localhost:5000/api/Test/getTest
Response Body
no content
Response Code
0
Response Headers
{
  "error": "no response from server"
```

Headers+body when I don't put any etiquette:

```
Curl
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' 'http://localhost:5000/api/Test/getTest'
Request URL
http://localhost:5000/api/Test/getTest
Response Body
0
Response Code
200
Response Headers
{
  "date": "Tue, 17 Jan 2017 22:49:14 GMT",
  "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
  "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  "server": "Kestrel",
  "": ""
}
```

Comment: If you could include an example of the http call coming into your controller that would help. Please include all headers, body and what http method you're using.

Comment: I added the http call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm betting that mixing a [FromBody] and [FromServices]on an action method is what is failing. [FromServices]is a construct to enable inversion of control to inject instances of a service into your controller. Strictly speaking from an IOC background, injecting a value into an action method is a bad idea in general so I'm surprised to see this functionality even exists.

To get it working move your [FromServices] argument to a constructor for your controller and then inside your action method you can reach into this service for the value that you need.

```
public class MySimpleController
{
    private GetTestByIdQueryHandler _handler;
    public MySimpleController([FromServices] GetTestByIdQueryHandler handler)
    {
        _handler = handler
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("getTest")]
    public int GetTest([FromBody]GetTestByIdQuery query)
    {
        return _handler.SomeMethod(query.TestId);   
    }
}
```